# What language is this, Simplified Chinese, or...?

Tags: character-identification

I'm adding a Chinese translation to my [videos], [2](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJv0STX-xSkapow54orIJ6g) and I want to know if this translation is Simplified Chinese or what? Here's an image:
[image]

Comment: It is simplified Chinese.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it is Simplified Chinese, just looking at some of the characters (e.g 他们 is simplified whereas 他們 would be traditional).

Answer (score 3):

Simplified Chinese.
But to me this doesn't sound like nice spoken language, maybe because it's translated from bable or somewhere else.

Comment: Chapter 1 verse 5 declares monotheism. It's from the Qur'an. You can listen to the verses (first seven) from here: (https://youtu.be/oB04xPG86nM) Any questions you can ask me, in shaa Allah I will answer.

Comment: @thatonedodobird please do not declare monotheism in a non-monotheism related forum. It is an incredibly offensive statement to people of other cultures and religions. You can ask Chinese-related questions but keep your missionary evangelicalism far away.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely simplified Chinese, all you are looking for is here, include English and other versions:
http://koran.link/zh__1/
http://koran.link/zh__2/